# My Keyboard Enter is not working to submit the form in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have a form in that my keyboard enter is not working in Android.

This is my **signin.page.html**:

```
<form [formGroup]="userlogindet" (ngSubmit)="UserLoginDetails()">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="newitem2">
              <ion-input placeholder="Email*" type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p *ngIf="userlogindet.get('email').errors && userlogindet.get('email').dirty && userlogindet.get('email').touched"
              class="myp2">EMAIL_NOT_VALID</p>
            <ion-item class="newitem2">
              <ion-input placeholder="Password*" type="password" formControlName="password" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-input type="hidden" formControlName="social_type" hidden></ion-input>
          </ion-list>
          <ion-button [disabled]="!userlogindet.valid" class="mybtn1" type="submit" color="danger" (keyup.enter)="enablelogintracking()" expand="full" fill="solid">Login
          </ion-button>
</form>
```

In this html file, I have a signin page in which I have the login button but it is not working when using the keyboard enter.

I have also used the `(keyup.enter)` after that also it is not working.

Any help is much appreciated.